# Exponential Integral Solution

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration

```
Integrate[ Exp[-x] - Exp[-x - b*Sqrt[-a + x^2]], {x, Sqrt[a], Infinity}]
```

If anyone has mathematica pro, can i please get the solution to this integral? a and b are real positive numbers

Comment: What is *Mathematica*Pro? I never heard about it.

Answer (score 1):

I think this integral isn't solveable. MMA Version 8.0 can't do neither the definite integral nor the indefinite one. Also the rule-based-integrator of Albert Richt  (http://www.apmaths.uwo.ca/~arich/ ) can't do it. Therefore it remains numerical integration

```
    int[a_, b_] := 
       NIntegrate[
         Exp[-x] - Exp[-x - b*Sqrt[-a + x^2]], {x, Sqrt[a], Infinity}]

    Plot3D[int[a, b], {a, 0, 11}, {b, 0, 13}, 
         AxesLabel -> {a, b, NIntegrate}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, Can u recommend specific numerical integration method? @Akku14

Comment: @Kanwal Zaidi    The function to integrate here makes no problems, therefore you can leave Mathematica the automatic choise of the integration method like I did above with NIntegrate.